# Migrations on Through Model Django Many to Manyo Field

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model used in a ManyToManyField that I want to change.

- User
- Teacher

  ```
    -  ManytoManyField through TeacherRelation
  ```
- TeacherRelation
- NewModel

I want to change the foreign key of the TeacherRelation so it uses NewModel instead of Teacher . I already have data That I dont want to loose on the db, so I would like to know what's the best way to make this kind of migrations.  Im concerned about issues like:

- Will I have to delete the previous entries on the db that used the other foreign key?
- Is there a way to find all the previous entries and replace them with the correct new primary key? I think I'll have to write a script for that... But where and when should I place it and run it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can manually duplicate the table. If you are using postgres, you can use PGadmin III or the console. for sqlite you ca send basic SQL commands to duplicate Teacher.

After Duplicating teacher, just change the original teacher table name to "NewModel" and build it as you wish :)

Easiest option IMO.